# Find the location nearest to the current location from an array of three locations and compare that which one is nearest to the current location

Tags: android, api, android-gps

```
ArrayList<LatLng> arrayList= new ArrayList<LatLng>();
LatLng near = new LatLng(33.549232, 73.125256);
LatLng pass = new LatLng(33.549844, 73.125849);
LatLng qareeb = new LatLng(33.549603, 73.124201);                                               


public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap= googleMap;
    for (int i =0; i<arrayList.size();i++){
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arrayList.get(i)).title("Marker").snippet("and snippet")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Main Yahan hn");
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(arrayList.get(i),15));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
        /*mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f));*/
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arrayList.get(i)));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    }
}
```

Above is my code and I want to create 3 points which compare to my current location that which one is near to the current location.

Answer (score 0):

The question which you are asking and the code which you have posted are not complete. The code simply enables `GoogleMaps` on the `Activity`. Instead of coding the entire solution to you, I would explain you the logic and expect you try it out at your end and repost the updated answer here if required.

**Steps:**

1. Fetch the current location of the device using `FusedLocationProviderClient` and store the value in a variable (say `currentLocation`). ([Get the last known location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current))
2. Use `Location` class to find the `distance` between `point1` and `currentLocation`. (say `d1`). ([distanceBetween](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D)))
3. Use the same process to find the distances between `point2` and `point3` from the `currentLocation`.
4. Now you will have 3 `distance` variables, `d1`, `d2` and `d3`. I guess you'll be able to find the shortest of these easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate distance between two location and then compare the distance.

```
 private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1))
            * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
            + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1))
            * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
            * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    return (dist);
}

private double deg2rad(double deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

private double rad2deg(double rad) {
    return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

You can use this as below code

```
  LatLng near = new LatLng(33.549232, 73.125256);
        LatLng pass = new LatLng(33.549844, 73.125849);
        LatLng qareeb = new LatLng(33.549603, 73.124201);
        double distance = distance(near.latitude, near.longitude, pass.latitude, pass.longitude);
```